# Namespaces in Php/Laravel

Tags: laravel, namespaces

Suppose some controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controller

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Auth;

class MemberController extends Controller {

//some code

}
```

Where do `Validator` and `Auth` belong to (so I can see their defintion) and what exactly are they?
I've one more question: [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) (Laravel 5.6 documentaton) it says

> we will use the validate method provided by the
>   Illuminate\Http\Request object.

and when I check [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html) for more information, there's no `validate` method!

I'd really appreciate it if anyone can help me with these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Validator` and `Auth` are aliases for the Facades of the same name in `Illuminate\Support\Facades`. They are a static proxy for an instance of a class. You can read about them in the Laravel docs about Facades.

The aliases for these are configured in `config/app.php` `'aliases'` array.

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades)

For `$request->validate(...)`:

It is a **macro**. Macros allow you to add functionality to classes that implement macro functionality at run time.

The `Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider@registerRequestValidation` sets this macro on `Illuminate\Http\Request` to allow for a `validate` method.

```
/**
 * Register the "validate" macro on the request.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function registerRequestValidation()
{
    Request::macro('validate', function (array $rules, ...$params) {
        return validator()->validate($this->all(), $rules, ...$params);
    });
}
```

For a quick read about macros in Laravel check out my article:

[asklagbox blog - Using Macros in Laravel](https://asklagbox.com/blog/laravel-macros)